# How to use the same file extension for different major-modes

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I use a custom version of `org-mode` called `lawlist-org-mode` -- every function and variable have the prefix `lawlist-` and the modified version has many custom features that are not available in the stock version.  Occasionally, I like to use the stock `org-mode` version -- however, that requires manually modifying the `auto-mode-alist` and then restarting Emacs.  This is necessary due to the function and variable `org-agenda-files` and the check that `org-mode` performs to verify that the proper major-mode is present.  Is there an efficient method to modify this programmatically depending upon the function being called?

The stock `org-mode` needs this entry:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.todo\\'" . org-mode))
```

The custom version called `lawlist-org-mode` needs this entry:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.todo\\'" . lawlist-org-mode))
```

**Examples**:

- If I call `M-x org-agenda`, the `.todo` files needs to be in `org-mode`.
- If I call `M-x lawlist-org-agenda`, the `.todo` file needs to be in `lawlist-org-mode`.

---

**Some Ideas**:  The `org-agenda-files` are generally accessed by org-agenda functions using the following lines of code -- `(org-agenda-files nil 'ifmode) . . . (while (setq file (pop files))`.  Perhaps modifying the function `org-agenda-files` would be an option?

Comment: Completely OT, but I'm curious: What kinds of features does your version of `org-mode` provide that are not in the stock version? Got a link to an online repo hosting your code? I'd love to check it out :)

Comment: @itsjeyd -- The first link is code compatible with `org-toodledo.el` that displays a custom agenda buffer with the headline + deadline / scheduled + notes: https://github.com/lawlist/lawlist-org -- This second link provides compatibility with a 3-month and 12-month calendar where certain todo entries are marked automatically on the calendar (e.g., birthdays, appointments, court holidays) etc.:  https://github.com/lawlist/calendar-yearly-scroll-by-month  My custom version of org-mode / calendar-mode provides some additional stuff, but those two links are the main ingredients.

Comment: @itsjeyd -- I terms of the custom `*Org Agenda*` buffer, I have three main types of searches that all display the headline + deadline / scheduled + notes:  a deadline / scheduled search based on `org-agenda-list`, `org-tags-view` for tags, and `org-search-view` for a keyword search.  I have additional sorting criteria for the `*Org Agenda*` buffer that organize undated and dated todo, alphabetic, and grouping -- e.g., tasks, events, undated, done, and contacts.  I have the same general type of editing that is available from the `*Org Agenda*` buffer -- e.g., timestamps, todo, content.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info + links, I'll check them out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FUNCTION` part of an `auto-mode-alist` entry (i.e., the cdr) is just a function. It is called, in principle to set up a major mode. But it can do anything.

In particular, you could have an entry `("\\.todo\\'" . foo)`, where function `foo` conditionally calls either `lawlist-org-mode` or `org-mode`.

E.g, it could use `lawlist-org-mode` when the moon is full and `org-mode` otherwise.  Or it could test a global variable, which you set when you want to switch from one to the other. And so on.

At least that's my reading of the `auto-mode-alist` doc string. I've never tried it.